# How to reinstall correctly package ubuntu-restricted-extras

Tags: codecs, reinstall

I had a DNS problem when I went to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package on my ubuntu 23.04. Due to this problem the fonts were not downloaded and also the codec packs.

The DNS issue has been fixed. However, when uninstalling and reinstalling the ubuntu-restricted-extras package, it only downloads the main package and no longer starts downloading fonts and other codec dependencies.

I would like to know how to completely uninstall the package to do a clean install as if it were the first time. I have tried the remove and purge options but to no avail.

Comment: Please try: `sudo apt install --reinstall --install-recommends ubuntu-restricted-extras` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found that all packages `(cabextract chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-vaapi liba52-0.7.4 libaribb24-0 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra59 libcdio19 libmpeg2-4 libopencore-amrnb0 libopencore-amrwb0 libsidplay1v5 libva-wayland2 patch python3-debconf python3-debian ubuntu-restricted-addons ubuntu-restricted-extras unrar update-notifier-common)` were already installed correctly. Except the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` that had not downloaded the fonts.

So I ran `apt purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and then `apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and it worked. Thanks